# How to auto-create tables in a Azure SQL DB from csv files in Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

i know there is a way to create one single table from multiple csv files, but how about if i want to create a table for each csv file in Azure Data Factory?

Comment: your question is very broad.  Yes, you can do either, look at Copy Activity in data factory.  I suggest trying it out and if you run into problems you can ask new questions that are more specific, be sure to add enough detail that someone can help you.  Here is the data factory documentation which has tutorials and samples https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/

Comment: please add more details about what you have tried and if you are getting any error.